# For Loop In Python using sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I need to create a FOR loop in Python that will repeat steps 1-2 1,00 times.

1. Split sample randomly into training test using a 632:368 ratio.
2. Build the model using the 63.2% training data and compute R square in holdout data.

I can't seem to grab the R square for the dataset :

[image]

```
 y=data['Amount']

 xall = data
 xall.drop(["No","Amount", "Class"], axis = 1, inplace = True) 

 for seed in range(10_00):
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xall, y, 
 test_size=0.382, 
  random_state=seed)


 modelall = LinearRegression()
 modelall.fit(xall, y)
 modelall = LinearRegression().fit(xall, y)
 r_sq = modelall.score(xall, y)
 print('coefficient of determination:', r_sq)
```

Comment: Why do u want to do 100 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fit the model using the TRAINING data and estimate the score using the TEST data.**

Use this:

```
y=data['Amount']
xall = data
xall.drop(["No","Amount", "Class"], axis = 1, inplace = True) 

for seed in range(100):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xall, y, test_size=0.382, random_state=seed)

    modelall = LinearRegression()
    modelall.fit(X_train, y_train)
    r_sq = modelall.score(X_test, y_test)
    print('coefficient of determination:', r_sq)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting a linear model to the whole dataset (xall) with a different seed number. Linear regression should give you the same output irrespective of the seed value.